# Wireshark not showing post data

Tags: post, filter, wireshark

I'm trying to find the post data that gets sent when I log in to Yahoo.com using Wireshark (I need to know it for webscraping purposes, and looking at the Html hasn't worked). I can filter by post requests (http.request.method == "POST"), but I'm pretty sure I'm not seeing the request because I will log in to Yahoo manually and the list of post requests on Wireshark won't change.

Any idea what's happening? Every other thread that I've read just recommends filtering by http.request.method == "POST", but that isn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging over TLS (https://...) then the packet will be encrypted and Wireshark will not be able to tell that it is a POST request.